# Detecting socket closing using boost::asio in Windows

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, winsock, disconnect

So I have a service method that uses `io_service::poll()` to process any currently-ready read/write events:

```
void Foo::service()
{
  io.poll(); // boost::asio::io_service
  if (socket.is_open())
    if (socket.available())
      notifyReadyToRead();
    else
      notifyReadyToWrite();
}
```

However, I'd also like to trigger behavior if the remote socket closes (gracefully or otherwise).  I know that Winsock can handle this, as it raises a network event in this circumstance.  Boost Asio sockets, however, have no built-in support for this as far as I can see.

I've tried reading and writing a zero-byte packet to the socket to test it for errors, but it appears that the implementation simply bails successfully if you pass it `boost::asio::buffer(socket, 0)` without actually checking the socket.

I've also heard that leaving a hanging read operation could work, but I'm not sure how to manage this while still allowing regular `boost::asio::read` and 'boost::asio::write` operations to work correctly.

Finally, adding a ping operation to the app-level protocol is a no-go; this class is intended to be used generically, and even if it wasn't I cannot change the remote side's protocol.

While I'd prefer a portable solution, a Windows-specific solution would be sufficient, even if it means grabbing the native handle and enumerating events that way.  (This occurred to me, but `WSAEnumNetworkEvents` clears the internal record of events, so I suspect it would cause problems if the boost::asio implementation depended on reading it.)

Comment: There is no support on any OS for notification of a remote socket that becomes silently unavailable/unreachable - the protocol does not and can not support it.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, you have to implement some application-level mechanism to detect all kinds of disconnection.
There were numerous discussions on boost/asio ML on this topic, [here is on of them](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/5142).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the socket option TCP_KEEPALIVE, but still need a pending read operation in order to receive a notification of the failed read.